# glew32.dll run time error

Tags: opengl, visual-c++

I successfully compiled my OpenGL program in MSVC 2008, But I am getting a Run time error as follows

> "This application has failed to start because glew32.dll was not found. Re-installing the application may fix this problem."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea how you managed to link the object files without the GLEW .lib file. Have you downloaded the GLEW library and put the .DLL file in the wrong place, perhaps? The .DLL file should be in the same directory as your OpenGL application that uses it, or in your Windows directory.

Also note that if you launch the application from within Visual Studio, it looks for the .DLL files in the project directory instead of the release/debug directories.

Comment: Thanks that helps. I hadn't included the  .dll file in proper location

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the file glew32.dll into the same directory as the binary exe that you compiled.